# Open print dialog automatically when PDF opened, using iText

Tags: java, javascript, pdf, itext

I need to be able provide the print dialog automatically when a pdf is opened. I need to do it with javascript and I was wondering if it is possible for me to append said javascript using iText? It would be much cleaner for me to do so because I am currently already utilizing the iText library. Otherwise is there a better way to do this? Currently using:

```
Document document = new Document();
document.add(New Paragraph("<script type="text/javascript">print();</script>"));
```

This, however, makes no changes to the pdf but still does not print when it is opened.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, the browser doesn't know _when_ the PDF is open, and surely can't access the separate process for the PDF to tell to be printed.

Comment: I've been told you can automatically print a pdf using javascript see: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php

However my question is if you can insert this javascript using iText

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did something like this without Javascript, using iText API calls:

```
PdfWriter writer = ...;
PdfAction action = new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG);
writer.setOpenAction(action);
```