# Open print dialog automatically when PDF opened, using iText7

Tags: itext7

I use **iText7** to generate a PDF and then open it in a new tab.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
String filename = "C:\\temp\\first-output2.pdf";
headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);
headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

The intent of the user is always to print, so displaying the PDF and letting him click the print button is inconvenient. That's why I want to **open the print dialog immediately when the PDF opens**.

This solution did not work

[Open print dialog automatically when PDF opened, using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676541/open-print-dialog-automatically-when-pdf-opened-using-itext)

because PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG does not exist in iText7.

I also tried various JavaScript options that didn't work, like

```
PdfAction action = PdfAction.createJavaScript("this.print(true);\\r");
```

How can I open the print dialog directly after page load?

Comment: You are aware that support for open actions or JavaScript might be limited in some PDF viewers?

Comment: If anyone uses a limited PDF viewer, he shall be limited. I'd be happy with a solution that works for the Adobe Reader.

Comment: OK. I merely asked because here are so many questions by people who based on a proof-of-concept with Adobe Reader (JavaScript enabled) promised their respective customer a functionality working on every PDF viewer and configuration...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open print dialog on document open, you need to use `this.print(true);` JavaScript code.

You can add such an action in `iText7` in the following way:

```
PdfAction printAction = new PdfAction();
printAction.put(PdfName.S, PdfName.JavaScript);
printAction.put(PdfName.JS, new PdfString("this.print(true);\r"));
pdfDocument.getCatalog().setOpenAction(printAction);
```